# Where to rent/watch German movies with German subtitles

Tags: learning

I'm an intermediate German learner and I would love to learn the language better by watching original German movies with German subs, because then I can see what is being said and understand it more or less. (I don't really learn from watching with English subs).

Now I have been trying to find these but I can't access sites like lovefilm.de and videobuster.de because of geographical restrictions... And I haven't found any for the films mentioned below on sites like opensubtitles. Does anyone have a suggestion?

I want to see films like Das Boot, Die Welle, Die fetten Jahre sind vorbei, Der Himmel über Berlin, Die Fälscher, Nirgendwo in Afrika, Das Wunder von Bern, Christiane F, or the show Berlin Berlin.

Let me know!

Answer (score 2):

The first problem to solve: find *German* movies for which *German* subtitles have been produced at all. Who would use them? Beside learners like you, it's mainly hearing impaired people, and they are not the most influential customer group... I checked out the titles that you listed - only 3 of them have DVD editions with German subtitles (Das Boot, Der Himmel über Berlin, Nirgendwo in Afrika).

My recommendation: checkout (e.g. by looking up on Amazon) which of the DVDs you are interested in have German subtitles and then try to get them at a local rental store or for sale (and later re-sale) 2nd hand. For the latter I can recommend [Tauschticket](http://www.tauschticket.de/) and [Booklooker](http://www.booklooker.de/) beside the usual "big players". Don't know how difficult it is to make sellers there ship DVDs to the Netherlands, but I would assume it is possible.

Another way: try German TV if you have acces to it in the Netherlands (e.g. via satellite). Some programs come with subtitles on videotext.

Comment: I did a similar search to the one that you did and I could find an edition of *Die fetten Jahre sind vorbei* with subtitles for the hearing impaired. I agree that it will be difficult to rent something that specific and that one might have to resort to buying.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect support for subtitles from online video streaming. I had a similar idea and didn't find video streaming with subtitles. I'm 100% certain that lovefilm.de is not supporting it.

My suggestion is renting DVDs. Often DVDs have more than one audio track and subtitles in various languages. At least in Europe this is the case.

Anyway, if you would like to try streaming services on your own, you can always overcome geo-blocking limitations by using a VPN or secure DNS services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think the physical rental stores in the Netherlands (where I live) have a lot of DVDs of German films, but I'll try to find some.

The list proxies located in Germany on letushide.com and xroxy.com didn't work at all for me (in Firefox), perhaps you know some that do work? (Web proxies didn't let me use Silverlight for streaming).

Comment: @Skandrino In the Netherlands you will have the same region code (2) as in Germany, hence you will be able to play all DVD from the German market. Most DVD have multi-lingual audio and subtitle tracks. Therefore you should definitely find something. Since you also live in the EU some online rental services may ship to the Netherlands too - just ask them. Good luck!

Comment: @Skandrino You can try http://incloak.com/vpn/. You can try their servers for free, but not sure about about stearming experience

Comment: Maybe there is a local library which also lends DVDs? Ours does, and you can select the subtitles.